# How can I filter to get only all the tracking_id with the higher datetime in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, filter

I want to filter this dataframe

[image]

So that i get the only all the id_tracking with the higher datetime. In this example it will only get rid of index=1 because their is the same id_tracking but with a newer datetime.

Comment: `df.groupby(['id_tracking']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['fixed_at'], ascending=False).head(1))`

Comment: and if you also want only the latitud and longitude to be negative?

Comment: `df.groupby(['id_tracking']).apply(lambda x: x[(x['latitud'] < 0) & (x['longitude '] < 0)].sort_values(['fixed_at'], ascending=False).head(1))`